# External DSL for CRUD code generation for multiple frameworks

Tags: scala, groovy, dsl, xtext

I am developing a general purpose CRUD code generator application. The idea is that codes/files (model, controller, view) for common insert, update, list, delete etc. operations will be automatically generated from model definition (like the definition used in Grails). But the generated code can be for any framework, e.g. Play (Scala or Java version) or Django or Grails or whatever framework user wants to use it for, even AngularJs. That is, same model definition can be used for generating code for any framework.

My question is, what can I use for this task - Scala or Groovy or some DSL specialized tools like Xtext?

Comment: Checkout http://yeoman.io/

Comment: @James I cannot understand how yeoman can help for my requirement. I mean, say, if I have 3 model classes (student, teacher, class), will yeoman generator create the controllers/views/APIs (say, for Play framework) for me? Or is it the underlying framework's task?

Comment: Probably I misunderstood your question. Are you looking for an existing generator to the above task? Or are you looking for a framework/tool with which you can create a generator for your case? If it's the later, you can use yeoman.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good case for a DSL. A DSL can be summed up as the following 3 elements:

1. Abstract Syntax: the concepts of your DSL. Here you want to specify CRUD applications.
2. Concrete Syntax(es): a way to materialize your Abstract Syntax. As a programmer, the first thought is often text-based syntaxes, but you could also use a graphical or tree-like syntax, or even simply a GUI with text fields and checkboxes.
3. Semantics: the meanings of your DSL. Here you want to generate code.

I'll now suggest *some* solutions which are based on Java and come from the Eclipse Modeling ecosystem.

1. [Eclipse EMF](https://eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) implements standards for the definition of so-called "metamodels" (basically abstract syntaxes). In the Eclipse world, EMF is the base for a lot of tooling.
2. Assuming you have an EMF metamodel, textual syntaxes can be specified using [Eclipse Xtext](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/), and graphical syntaxes using [Eclipse Sirius](https://www.eclipse.org/sirius/). Note that you can also develop your own GUI in Java and create your model using the EMF Java APIs. Also note that Xtext can create your metamodel for you based on the grammar you want for your text-based syntax. This is nice if you don't want to dive too deep into EMF it self (thus steps 1 and 2 are one and the same).
3. [Eclipse Acceleo](https://eclipse.org/acceleo/) provides a template language specifically designed to generate text, including code. Once again, you can also write your code generator using plain Java, or any JVM-based language thanks to the EMF Java APIs. If you use Xtext, there is also a facility for [including an Xtend-based code generator](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/103_domainmodelnextsteps.html#tutorial-code-generation) alonside your syntax.